# Android Studio stuck during the installation

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I was installing Android Studio but has been stuck there for almost **four** **hours**.

What can I do? It is done? Should I cancel it?

[image: Image_Error]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/install

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is done it will show you a finish button, it shouldn't take 4 hours I think you should cancel it and try to install a clean one by deleting previous files.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I'll have to do that. Thanks for the advice.